# Precedence while overloading operators C++

Tags: c++, operators, overloading, operator-precedence

I have a class, in which I have overloaded some operators. My code is like this:

```
myClass << 12 << 14 << 21 << 44
```

This works well, firstly runs `myClass << 12`, then `myClass << 14`.

But I have a problem if I try to do something like this:

```
myClass << 12 << 14+18 << 36 << 14 << 47
```

The operator `+` is overloaded too, and the problem is that `14+18` runs before `myClass << 12`. I really need to execute firstly `myClass << 12` and then `14+18`. How can I achieve this?

Edit:

I want to put some numbers and arrays of numbers into a stream. The part of the numbers is solved. As for the arrays of numbers, I was doing something like this:

```
myClass << 12 << myClass(array,10) << 21 << 19
```

Where operator `()` is overloaded, array is the array of numbers and 10 is the length of the array. I'm doing this because I need some way of keeping the length of the array, but the problem is that `myClass(array,10)` is executed before `myClass << 12` . So, in this case, I want firstly to put `12` into the stream and then my arrays of numbers, and I need to know its length.

And, I don't want to use this solution:

```
myClass << 12
myClass << myClass(array,10)
```

Because I want to use my code as a library, so my intention is that the end user has flexibility to write everything in a line.

Comment: You can't overload `operator+` for two ints. What does your *real* code look like?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I'm not using the operator+ like that. It just was an example.

Comment: Have you tried using parenthesis to force evaluation order?  Such as `myClass << 12 << (14 + 18) << 36 << 14 << 47`.  This is the suggested coding style when outputting to standard streams.

Comment: Why is it a problem that `myClass(array,10)` is executed first?  What does that constructor _do_ exactly?

Comment: @Mooing Duck It's not a constructor (I thought it was at first too, until I reread the question about 3-4 times), it's `operator()` and presumably instead of returning a string representing the array it immediately writes to the stream.

Comment: Yes, I want to write it to the stream. The problem is that it's executed before `myClass << 12`.

Comment: @MarkB: Is it viable for `operator()` to return a temporary instead of writing directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so let's simplify and break down what's going on here. The first part of your call evaluates to something like this:

`myClass << 12 << myClass(array,10)` becomes `myClass.operator<<(12).operator<<(myClass(array, 12)` which when notionally spelling out the implicit `this` parameter becomes something like `operator<<(operator<<(myClass, 12), myClass(array, 10))`

Now the only thing the standard says about the order of executing `operator<<(myClass, 12)` and `myClass(array, 10)` is that both will be executed before the outermost `operator<<` is called. In your case, it elected to execute the `operator()` first.

Now, how do we achieve the result you want? First, you could put the parts of the single statement into multiple statements to force the order you desire.

Alternately, you could process the array totally differently. I'd suggest a `format_array` function:

```
std::string format_array(array, 10)
{
    // Do stuff
    return string representation of array
}

myClass << 12 << format_array(array,10) << 21 << 19
```

Original answer based on a different question phrasing:
Since you can't overload `operator+(int, int)` my psychic question reading skills tell me that your class has both `operator<<` and `operator+` and that the `operator+` is some sort of a state-manipulator on your class, that you want to happen after you insert 12 and 14 into the stream.

In that case....*don't do that*. That's NOT what `operator+` is for and why standard streams use manipulators.

But if you absolutely insist: `(myClass << 12 << 14) +18 << 36 << 14 << 47`

Comment: Thanks. I've editted my question.I hope it's better explained.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into an issue with [sequence  points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).  If you want to run the insertions in a guaranteed order then you would have to use

```
myClass << 12;
myClass << 14+18;
myClass << 36;
myClass << 14;
myClass << 47;
```

Comment: No, because the function arguments must be calculated before the function can be called.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to do that. I want to use my code as a library, so I want that the end user has the flexibility to write all in a line.